# Java annotation execute a method within the annotation declaration(usage for android)

Tags: java, android, methods, annotations

I'm fairly new to the annotation terms. 
I have read some sources and came to the conclusion that non answered my question.
Perhaps I googled using the wrong search. Perhaps I overlook, or mayhbe im just clueless..

Anyway here is the deal.

I am busy writing an application that requires "role validation".

To do this I want to use an annotation.

So something along the line of:

```
@interface Validate (){

}
```

What I aim to achieve is sometihng along the lines of:

```
public @interface Validate() {
   public Validate() {
      //Do validation stuff
     return true/false
   }
}
```

So basically I want to define methods within the annotation.
I want to be able to call

```
@Validate
public void methodThatRequiresAdminRole() {
  doStuff();
}
```

Only admins should be able to enter this method. Otherwise an error should be generated.

so if @validate returns true, the method should be executed

Sorry if I am really unclear. I am not quite sure how to properly ask what I want. 
So I hope the examples tell the stories.

Hope to read tips and perhaps even an answer soon.
Thanks.

** EDIT **

I need to stress out the fact that the code must be used on an android application.
So I prefer to not use strange frameworks not meant for android. I have no problem adding a custom library that gives the functionality without any kind of application framework.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Annotations are meta data. What you need to write is an annotation processor. An annotation in itself cannot accomplish the validation logic. The annotation processor will look at the annotations and then do the validation and control the application flow. This SO answer has a good explanation [Can Java Annotations help me with this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460001/can-java-annotations-help-me-with-this/1460047#1460047)

You also need to annotate the annotation with @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) so that the annotation information is preserved till the runtime.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
public @interface Validate() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice aswell as the link. I know what to do for my next step. So im helped.

Comment: You are welcome. Check out this link as well for the implementation of a simple annotation processor http://www.horstmann.com/corejava/cj7v2ch13ex.pdf .

Answer (score 2):

Note, this might be quite off-topic.  Using [spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop) with, processing the annotations is fairly straightforward:

Create an aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class RoleCheckAspect {
  @Before("@annotation(your.package.Validate)")
  public void doAccessCheck() throws Exception {
    // Do validation stuff
    if (!valid)
      throw new IllegalAccessException("foo");
    }
  }
}
```

Set-up your aspect:

In META-INF/aop.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
  "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
  <weaver>
    <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
    <include within="your.package..*" />
  </weaver>
  <aspects>
    <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
    <aspect name="com.bac.bsl.nonproc.TestAspect" />
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Set-up [load time weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-aj-ltw)

In the spring context:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

Ensure that the spring-agent is started with your app:

```
java -javaagent:/path/to/spring-agent.jar -classpath $CP your.package.MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this with annotations alone. They are meant to provide meta information about code elements and not processing logic.
To actually implement the restriction on the annotated methods invocation you will need to check the access by hand inside or outside the method or inject such a check using something like http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/

Comment: in case you are familiar with .NET. I am looking for "attributes" I was / am convinced that is exactly what an annotation is. Could I be wrong in this case? It just came to my mind. Thanks for your answer btw. It does look like it can not be achieved. I will let a few mins go by, see what answers pop up. Otherwise I will mark this.

Comment: @Joey AspectJ can be used for android development but it is limited to use compile time weaving meaning you can only control execution of methods you have the source code for.

Comment: @Joey Yes Java Annotations are the equivalent to .NET Attributes. You can add annotations to methods and these annotations can contain data, but not processing logic that is executed on a method call for example. This is more the concern of an so called aspect in the terms of AOP.

Comment: I am using PlayFramework and it has an annotation @Secured which will check if a cookie exists and then validates that cookie in the session cache so it can be done. I am not exactly sure as I can't seem to see how they do it in scala but I am sure it can be performed without AspectJ